# I keep getting this error in mysql

Tags: mysql

i created a database for a nfl team. I created a table called players that holds bios info. Now i want to create a table called transactions that shows the trade transactions but  players to the active roster based from the primary key of players. But i keep getting this error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY(idplayer) REFERENCES players(playersid))' at line 8.`
`

```
create table transactions(
 transid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 type VARCHAR(30),
 fromteam VARCHAR(30),
 toteam VARCHAR(30),
 idplayer INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(transid),
 FORIEGN KEY(idplayer) REFERENCES players(playersid));
```

Please could someone help me out on similar experiences.

Comment: check the foreign key spelling

Comment: It's `FOREIGN` and not `FORIEGN`

Comment: typo error : its FOREIGN KEY not FORIEGN KEY

Answer (score 2):

I think you just misspelled FOREIGN :-)

Answer (score 0):

Typo, change

```
        FORIEGN KEY(idplayer) REFERENCES players(playersid));
```

to

```
        FOREIGN KEY(idplayer) REFERENCES players(playersid));
```